# Compiler error when using an inner class template in instantiating a class template

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes

GCC 7.5.0 is giving me an error message that I'm puzzled about. This is the smallest piece of code I can come with that generates the message:

```
template<template<typename> typename>
struct A
{

};

template<char>
struct X
{
    template<typename>
    struct Y
    {

    };
};

template<char c>
struct B : public A<X<c>::Y>
{

};
```

GCC 7.5.0 says:

```
../main.cpp:18:28: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<template<class> class<template-parameter-1-1> > struct A’
subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
 struct B : public A<X<c>::Y>
                            ^
../main.cpp:18:28: note:   expected a class template, got ‘X<c>::Y’
```

Is the problem perhaps that the argument to A in the inheritance clause must be a class template that sits at namespace level? This is not the case with X::Y. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do without putting Y inside of X. Application-specific stuff not shown seems to mandate it.

Comment: you can solve adding a `template`: `struct B : public A<X<a>::template Y>`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell the compiler that `X<c>::Y` is a template and not a type or variable. Try the following:

```
template<char c>
struct B : public A<X<c>::template Y>
{

};
```

Demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/3jWG1nK3z)

For a rather longer discussion of exactly when you need to specify this kind of thing and why, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) is very thorough.